# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Error finding "uri" property in

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

The title yields me some SO links but unfortunately I couldn't get them to work. I am totally new to SOAP. I have been given a wsdl link and there are some method I need to call through soap.

I am stuck at a particular point where it says

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Error finding "uri" property in
>   there error is generating at this code.

```
class SoapClientCompatibility extends SoapClient{
    public function __construct($wsdl, $options){
        // do things here, like:
        // download the wsdl using curl
    }}function soapClientWSSecurityHeader($user, $password){
  // Creating date using yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ format
  $tm_created = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
  $tm_expires = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', gmdate('U') + 180); //only necessary if using the timestamp element
  // Generating and encoding a random number
  $simple_nonce = mt_rand();
  $encoded_nonce = base64_encode($simple_nonce);
  // Compiling WSS string
  $passdigest = base64_encode(sha1($simple_nonce . $tm_created . $password, true));

  // Initializing namespaces
  $ns_wsse = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
  $ns_wsu = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd';
  $password_type = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest';
$encoding_type = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary';

  // Creating WSS identification header using SimpleXML
  $root = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');

  $security = $root->addChild('wsse:Security', null, $ns_wsse);
  //the timestamp element is not required by all servers
  $timestamp = $security->addChild('wsu:Timestamp', null, $ns_wsu);
  $timestamp->addAttribute('wsu:Id', 'Timestamp-28');
  $timestamp->addChild('wsu:Created', $tm_created, $ns_wsu);
  $timestamp->addChild('wsu:Expires', $tm_expires, $ns_wsu);

  $usernameToken = $security->addChild('wsse:UsernameToken', null, $ns_wsse);
  $usernameToken->addChild('wsse:Username', $user, $ns_wsse);
  $usernameToken->addChild('wsse:Password', $passdigest, $ns_wsse)->addAttribute('Type', $password_type);
  $usernameToken->addChild('wsse:Nonce', $encoded_nonce, $ns_wsse)->addAttribute('EncodingType', $encoding_type);
  $usernameToken->addChild('wsu:Created', $tm_created, $ns_wsu);



  // Recovering XML value from that object
  $root->registerXPathNamespace('wsse', $ns_wsse);
  $full = $root->xpath('/root/wsse:Security');
  $auth = $full[0]->asXML();
  print_r($auth);
  return new SoapHeader($ns_wsse, 'Security', new SoapVar($auth, XSD_ANYXML), true,'https://mywebsite.com');
}
class Valid {
    function Valid($hn, $vc) 
    {
        $this->healthNumber = $healthNumber;
        $this->versionCode = $versionCode;
    }
}
$hcvRequest = array(
    "healthNumber" => "1286844022",
    "versionCode" => "YX"
);
$valid = array(
    "hcvRequest" => $hcvRequest
);

$params = array(
    "requests" => $valid
);

$client = new SoapClientCompatibility('https://example.com/?wsdl');$client->__setSoapHeaders(soapClientWSSecurityHeader('someemail@email.com', 'somepassword'));
echo "<pre>";
$response = $client->__soapCall("validate", array($params));
print_r($client);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: can someone help with the issue ?

Comment: I have able to pass to soap request through the server, what I am missing at now is I am really not sure how should i add the Binary security token. Right now I am inserting my public key which I have copied from my cpanel's manage ssl certificate section.

Comment: Also there is a digest value in signedInfo section which says

`<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse ebs hcv idp msa soapenv" />
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />`

I am canonicalizing the xml element and then creating a hash with sha1 and the doing a base64_encode on that. What I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this page because I got an exception of `Error finding "uri" property` while using the php SoapClient.

In the end, for me, I found that the error was due to the fact that I was referencing a saved version of the WSDL file (saved locally) which was out of date. The webservice had changed, so once I deleted the local WSDL file and pulled down the latest version of it the error did not occur any longer.

Hopefully this will help any php SoapClient users who have the same issue.

Note that I pass a locally stored version of the WSDL file to the first argument of the SoapClient. I believe this means that the SoapClient does not pull the WSDL file down with every Soap request.